# Calendar calculation problems

Tags: java, calendar, string-formatting

My code is bellow, the problem is i need it to be able to make the calendar as if it was real for whatever input the user says, so if the users says i want it to start on Monday, in the year 1776, then it will work for that. How it works now is, it is only able to start on Sunday and every month start on Sunday so if the month before ends on Monday the calendar should begin the next month on Tuesday but it goes back to Sunday if thats what the user input anyone got a fix for this?

```
package calendaryear;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class calendaryear {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String month;
    String day;
    Scanner userinput = new Scanner(System.in);
    //enter the day!
    System.out.print("Enter day [0 is for Sunday, 1 is for moneday continued]:");
    int d = userinput.nextInt();
    //enter a year!
    System.out.print("Enter a year:");
    int y = userinput.nextInt();
    // for loop for 12 months!
    for (int m = 1; m <= 12; m++){
        switch (m) {
            case 1:
                month = "\n\t January";
                break;
            case 2:
                month = "\n\t February";
                break;
            case 3:
                month = "\n\t March";
                break;
            case 4:
                month = "\n\t April";
                break;
            case 5:
                month = "\n\t May";
                break;
            case 6:
                month = "\n\t June";
                break;
            case 7:
                month = "\n\t July";
                break;
            case 8:
                month = "\n\t August";
                break;
            case 9:
                month = "\n\t September";
                break;
            case 10:
                month = "\n\t October";
                break;
            case 11:
                month = "\n\t November";
                break;
            case 12:
                month = "\n\t December";
                break;
            default:
                month ="";
                }

        System.out.printf("%" + (34 + month.length()) / 2 + "s %s\n", month, y);
        System.out.println(String.format("%39S", "").replace(' ', '-'));
        System.out.printf("%-6s%-6s%-6s%-6s%-6s%-6s%-6s\n", "Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat");

        int l = 30 + ((m + (int)(m / 8.0)) % 2);
        if (m == 2) {
            if ((y % 4 == 0 && y % 100 != 0) || (y % 400 == 0)){
                l = 29;
            }else {
                l = 28;
            }
        }
        d = (d) % 7;
        switch (d) {
            case 0:
                day = "Sunday";
                break;
            case 1:
                day = "Moneday";
                break;
            case 2:
                day = "Tuesday";
                break;
            case 3:
                day = "Wednesday";
                break;
            case 4:
                day = "Thursday";
                break;
            case 5:
                day = "Friday";
                break;
            case 6:
                day = "Saturday";
                break;
            default:
                day = "";
        }
        if (d != 0) {
            System.out.print(String.format("%" + 6 * d + "s", ""));

        }

for (int i = 1; i <= l; i++)
{
System.out.printf("%-6d", i);
if (i % 7 == 0)  //<-- this part 
{
   System.out.println();
}
day += 1;
}
        System.out.print("");


    }
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your logic was partly correct. There were a few problems:

- To simplify, I replaced the modulus(%) operator with a counter.
- `day += 1`  is incorrect. That concatenates. You want `d += 1`
- You need to print the correct number of blank days before you print Day 1

Here's the corrected program:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    String month;
    String day;
    Scanner userinput = new Scanner(System.in);
    //enter the day!
    System.out.print("Enter day [0 is for Sunday, 1 is for moneday continued]:");
    int d = userinput.nextInt();
    //enter a year!
    System.out.print("Enter a year:");
    int y = userinput.nextInt();
    // for loop for 12 months!
    for (int m = 1; m <= 12; m++){
        switch (m) {
        case 1:
            month = "\n\t January";
            break;
        case 2:
            month = "\n\t February";
            break;
        case 3:
            month = "\n\t March";
            break;
        case 4:
            month = "\n\t April";
            break;
        case 5:
            month = "\n\t May";
            break;
        case 6:
            month = "\n\t June";
            break;
        case 7:
            month = "\n\t July";
            break;
        case 8:
            month = "\n\t August";
            break;
        case 9:
            month = "\n\t September";
            break;
        case 10:
            month = "\n\t October";
            break;
        case 11:
            month = "\n\t November";
            break;
        case 12:
            month = "\n\t December";
            break;
        default:
            month ="";
        }

        System.out.printf("%" + (34 + month.length()) / 2 + "s %s\n", month, y);
        System.out.println(String.format("%39S", "").replace(' ', '-'));
        System.out.printf("%-6s%-6s%-6s%-6s%-6s%-6s%-6s\n", "Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat");

        int l = 30 + ((m + (int)(m / 8.0)) % 2);
        if (m == 2) {
            if ((y % 4 == 0 && y % 100 != 0) || (y % 400 == 0)){
                l = 29;
            }else {
                l = 28;
            }
        }
        //d = (d) % 7;  ***** REMOVED *****
        switch (d) {
        case 0:
            day = "Sunday";
            break;
        case 1:
            day = "Moneday";
            break;
        case 2:
            day = "Tuesday";
            break;
        case 3:
            day = "Wednesday";
            break;
        case 4:
            day = "Thursday";
            break;
        case 5:
            day = "Friday";
            break;
        case 6:
            day = "Saturday";
            break;
        default:
            day = "";
        }
        if (d != 0) {
            //System.out.print(String.format("%" + 6 * d + "s", ""));   ***** REMOVED *****

        }

        /* print leading blank days (if any) */
        int daysprinted = 0;
        for (int k = 0; k < d; k++) {
            System.out.printf("%-6s", "");
            daysprinted++;
        }

        for (int i = 1; i <= l; i++)
        {
            System.out.printf("%-6d", i);
            daysprinted++;

            if (daysprinted == 7)  //<-- this part   ***** CHANGED *****
            {
                System.out.println();
                daysprinted = 0;
            }

            d += 1;     //***** day += 1 is INCORRECT; use d here *****
            if (d > 6)
                d = 0;  //WRAP AROUND

        }
        System.out.print("");
    }
}
```